# Proof of continuity correction for normal approximation to binomial distribution?

Tags: binomial-distribution

I am trying to better understand the conditions under which the application of continuity correction is appropriate for the normal approximation to the binomial distribution.

Everything I have found says "this is something you should do" or gives an intuitive explanation, but I would like to see a formal proof or paper that addresses continuity correction. Does anyone know where I might be able to find one?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By formal paper, you mean a scientific journal paper? Anyways, [this](http://www.johndcook.com/normal_approx_to_binomial.html) might help.

Comment: Thank you, that does help. I'm still not clear where 1/2 comes from, why not 49/100, so will leave this open for a little while to see if anyone else has resources